# How to check an element in array exists or not in java?

Tags: java, arrays, null

**Input Format:**

The first line has an integer . In each of the next  lines there will be an integer  denoting number of integers on that line and then there will be  space-separated integers. In the next line there will be an integer  denoting number of queries. Each query will consist of two integers x and y.

**Output Format:**

In each line, output the number located in yth position of xth line. If there is no such position, just print "ERROR!"

```
   public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = in.nextInt();
    Integer arr[][] = new Integer[x][];
    arr[x][100] = null; 
     for(int i=0;i < x;i++){
            int y = in.nextInt(); 
         for(int j = 0;j<y;j++){
             arr[i][j] = in.nextInt();
         }       
        }
    int z = in.nextInt();
     for(int k=0;k<z;k++){
         int p = in.nextInt();
         int q = in.nextInt();   
         if(arr[p-1][q-1] ==  null){

             System.out.printf("%s\n","ERROR!");

         }
          else 
              System.out.printf("%d\n",arr[p-1][q-1]); 

     }

}
```

When I run this I'm getting error as

```
 Solution.java:23: error: incomparable types: int and <null>
           if(arr[p-1][q-1] ==  null){
```

How do I avoid this error in future?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do but you can use an `Integer` array instead of an `int` array and initialize it's elements with `null`.

Comment: can you post more of your code?

Comment: Seems like a Problem from hackerrank. Please be more specific what you want to ask? You can also check if your code throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException for location which doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem.  When I compile your code, I get an error that is solved by adding an import statement.  Then when the code is runnable, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

But my guess is that your code was originally declaring `arr` like this:

```
int arr[][] = new int[x][];
```

Then this

```
if (arr[p-1][q-1] == null) {
```

will give you that the compilation error that you reported.

The error message is telling you that you cannot compare `arr[p-1][q-1]` with `null`, because `arr[p-1][q-1]` evaluated to an `int`, and a primitive type (such an `int`) is not comparable with `null`.

Why?  Because `null` is not a valid integer value.

---

> How to check an element in array exists or not in java?

It depends.

For an array whose base type is a primitive type, there is no way to do it.   Every element in (for example) an `int[]` exists, and has a value that is an integer.  There is simply no way for an element to "not exist" ... provided that the index for the element is in the range `0` to `array.length - 1`.

For an array whose base type is a reference type (e.g. `Integer`), an element can have the value `null`, and you could use that to mean that no value exists.  And if you do that an `== null` test is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
{
   //Your code..
    int p = in.nextInt();
    int q = in.nextInt();
    try
    {
        int r = arr[p-1][q-1];
        System.out.printf("%d\n",arr[p-1][q-1]);
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s\n","ERROR!");   
    }
}
```